# How to treat $dx$ when doing integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Determine: $\int{\frac{1}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2-5}}}dx$

**My attempt:**

$$\text{Let}\ x+2=\frac{1}{u}$$

$$\therefore dx=(-\frac{1}{u^2})du\tag{1}$$

In $(1)$, is $du$ being multiplied with $-\frac{1}{u^2}$ or is $du$ like an operator or something? Can I move $du$ around like it is being multiplied? For example, can I write the following:

$$dx=(-\frac{du}{u^2})$$

$$dx=du(-\frac{1}{u^2})$$

Comment: You can write these things. Treat $du$ like a formal quantity. Here I would try $x = \sqrt{5}\cosh(u)$ instead.

Comment: Yes, in this case you can sling $du$ and $dx$ around as if they were real numbers. This is because, by the chain rule,
$$
\int f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) \, dx=\int f(u) \, du
$$
where $u=g(x)$. If we write $du/dx=g'(x)$ and "multiply both sides by $dx$" to get $du=g'(x) \, dx$, then we obtain the RHS of the above equality, justifying the formal manipulation of the differentials.

Comment: Yes you can.  Notice also that $\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{-1}{u^2}$ because you defined $u$ as a function of $x$ and vice versa.

Comment: You can as long as you are just using the first differential.  If you go beyond the first differential, you need a slightly different notation, as the standard $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ won't work algebraically.  See my paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials".  The full notation for the second derivative (from the quotient rule) is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  Using this you can freely manipulate differentials just like in the first derivative.

Comment: In fact, slinging around the differential $\mathrm dx,$ the given expression can also be slightly condensed as $\displaystyle\int{\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x+2)\sqrt{x^2-5}}}.$ Sometimes the differential even disappears altogether: $\displaystyle\int f=\int f(u)\,\mathrm du=\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ can be read as the integral of the function $f.$